# which Prompt Dialog shall I use for password reset functionality

Tags: botframework

I am developing a simple chatbot for access functionality. I need to have prompt dialog for Password reset functionality. like If user account is forgotpassword/locked the, I am asking to user to secret question and if answer of sceret question is matching for the question then, i will generate the one time password else retry option to user..
here is my code.. boolChoice (it is an LuisIntent) is when user wants to rest password. then i will prompt

```
 if (boolChoice.ToLower().Equals("yes"))
            {
                PromptDialog.Text(
                context: context,
                resume: ResumeAfterSecretAnswer,
                prompt: "Ok. I need you to answer your secret question: "+getSecretQuestionForUser(),
                retry: "I didn't understand. Please try again.");
            }
private string getSecretQuestionForUser()
        {
            return "What is your favorite color?";
        }

private async Task ResumeAfterSecretAnswer(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {
            string answer = await result;
            //suppose right answer is blue.. then what next i need to do . do I need to prompt here or how do I compare and generate the one time password.
// need a flow,...
        }
```

now inside ResumeAfterSecretAnswer what i need to do if answer is matching then i need to prompt user to onetime passsword or if not matching then what i need to prompt him again. and which promptdialog i need to use PromoptDialog.Confirm or anything else..

I am little confuse with flow.. what should be the flow here..

Now i have changed the method...

I have changes the method now..

```
private async Task ResumeAfterSecretAnswer(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {
            string answer = await result;

            if (answer.ToLower() == getSecretAnswerForUser())
                await context.PostAsync("Your One time password is: "+ getOneTimePasswordForUser());
            else
                await context.PostAsync("The answers do not match. Please try again.");

            context.Wait(MessageReceived);

        }
```

what should I do in else part if answer do not match. i need to prompt the user again.. How and what should I do here...i achieve this.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call this again on the else, I suggest you to put it in a method:

```
PromptDialog.Text(
                context: context,
                resume: ResumeAfterSecretAnswer,
                prompt: "Ok. I need you to answer your secret question: "+getSecretQuestionForUser(),
                retry: "I didn't understand. Please try again.");
```

be careful with the context.wait(MessageReceived) from the else, it may throw an exception because of the multiple exits of the dialog